# react js reload or force rerender of a component to reflect change in back end

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that pulls articles from an api and shows them in three tables. These table contain liked, disliked and uncommented or unreviewed articles. The unreviewed table contains like and dislike buttons.
When the user clicks like or dislike i make a post request to the server using axios. This succesfully changes the database but i could not find a way to show the change in front end without manually reloading the app. this.forceUpdate does not work. Is there a way to reload the component so it makes those request and and render the change or is there another way to solve this.

Note. the three group of articles are pulled from the api using 3 get request not 1.

Edit:

Articles module

```
var Articles = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            unReviewed: null,
            liked: null,
            disliked: null
        };
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.getArticles();
    },
    getArtiles: function () {
        //3 api call here and set the response to unReviewed, liked and disliked
    },
    handleReview: function() {
        this.forceUpdate();
    },
    render: function() {
        var {unReviewed, liked, disliked} = this.state;
        if (//all three state are null) {
            return(<div>Loading...</div>);
        } else {
            return(
            <div>
                <h1>Articles</h1>
                <h2>New / Unreviewed</h2>
                <ArticleTable articles={unReviewed} onReview={this.handleReview}/>
                <h2>liked</h2>
                <ArticleTable articles={liked}/>
                <h2>disliked</h2>
                <ArticleTable articles={disliked}/>
            </div>
            );
        }
    }
});
```

ArticlesTable module

```
var ArticleTable = React.createClass({
    handleReview: function () {
        this.props.onReview();
    },
    render: function () {
        var {articles} = this.props;
        var renderData = () => {
            return articles.map((article) => {
                return (
                    <ArticleItem key={article.id} {...article} onReview={this.handleReview}/>
                );
            });
        };

        return(
            <table>
                <thead>//headers
                </thead>
                <tbody>{renderData()}</tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});
```

ArticleItem module

```
var ArticleItem = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
       //validating props
    },

    onReview: function (id) {
        //making post api call
        that.props.onReview();
    },

    render: function () {
        var {id, text, author, date, liked} = this.props;
        var that = this;
        if(liked == null){
           liked = "--";
        }
        var review = function () {
            if(liked == "--") {
                return(<span>
                    <button onClick={() => that.onReview(id)}>Like</button>
                </span>);
            }
            return null;
        };

        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{id}</td>
                //other parts of article
                <td>{review()}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Share your code. If you keep updated component's state it'll automatically render. But share your code and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Its hard to understand without some code. How does your component consumes the articles? in general, if it passed through props you will need to change the props, if state you will have to use setState with the new values. forceUpdate only works if the data is correct.

Answer (score 0):

To re-render you have to make a change to the component state.So you have to get the response from the backend and make a change to your component state.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it is say what the best approach is.

First off, there is `forceUpdate` which forces the `render` function to run again. But I'm assuming you actually need the API to be called again. So how about something like this?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            intervalId: null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const id = setInterval(this.fetchData, 5000);
        this.setState({intervalId: id});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
    }

    fetchData() {
        // Call your api
    }

    render() {
        ..
    }
}
```

This will call `fetchData` every 5 seconds. When data is fetched, if you update the state, then the `render` function will be reloaded.

Comment: calling api every 5 sec is something i would like to avoid. as this app  is going to be used in small office and database will update at most a dozen times a day. so making api call every 5 sec is overkill